# How to filter rows with WHERE clause before JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have 2 tables like below:

**Order**

```
Id, Name
```

**Product**

```
Id, OrderId, ...
```

I want to filter all products by particular order name. My T-SQL query:

```
SELECT o.Id, o.Name, p.Id
FROM Order o
INNER JOIN Product p ON o.Id = p.OrderId
WHERE o.Name = "TEST"
```

My products table can have thousand of rows, so I believe this SQL first joins all orders with all products and then having all the joined result set apply `WHERE` clause to select just those with TEST name.

It will be much better if the SQL first filters the `Order` table by name "TEST", and then make join of only those Orders instead of whole table.

So the question is how to execute `WHERE` before `JOIN`?

Comment: It should do exactly what you want it to. Just check the execution plan, and if it doesn't, there should be an index suggestion.

Comment: (1) Your query is not valid SQL Server syntax.  Are you sure it is tagged correctly?  (2) Normally, I would expect `Name` in the `products` table, not `orders`.

Comment: Replace double qoutes with single quotes to correct syntax error and you are OK. Optimizer is smart enough to choose a good plan for the query like that. Check execution plan as @RogerWolf said to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot specify *how* SQL runs the query except through the use of optimizer hints.  A standard SQL query only specifies what the results are, not the execution plan.  Typically, you are depending on the optimizer to choose the best execution plan.

For this query:

```
SELECT o.Id, o.Name, p.Id
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN
     Product p
     ON o.Id = p.OrderId
WHERE o.Name = 'TEST'
```

For performance, you want an index on `Orders(Name, Id)` and `Product(Orderid, p.Id)`.  This gives the optimizer the tools it needs to find the best execution plan.

These are covering indexes for the query, meaning that all columns are in the index, so the data pages do not need to be retrieved.  The execution plan should be looking up the appropriate orders based on `Name` and then fetching the appropriate product rows.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any problem that my Id of Order as well as Product is uniqueidentifier? I believe i have got 2 indexes, one per each Primary Key (Id) while i created this tables, so I need to add 2 more to cover all the fields?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner . . . There is no problem *querying* uniqueidentifiers.  However, if you don't initialize them correctly, you can fragment your table.  The recommended indexes here are for optimal performance.  Your queries may be okay, depending on your performance needs and the size of your data.

Comment: You say I need to create those indexes to gives the optimizer the tools. So without those indexes, the WHERE clause would not be executed before JOIN right? Or still?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner . . . Can't say.  You would need to look at the execution plan.  However, with the right tools, we are more confident the optimizer chooses the right path.  Note:  If the tables are small, it may still avoid the indexes and do full table scans.

Comment: Heh, you can tell it "how" to do it, but that's not the idea.. I agree with Gordon, the optimizer should be allowed (and helped) to choose the right plan.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan . . . That is a really good point.  I updated the answer.

Comment: In fact I make the question a little shorter, as table Order is almost exactly what I have, but the Product table got like ~~20 fields, so the Index Product(Id, OrderId) should be in fact Product(Id, OrderId1, Field1, Field2 ... FIeld20) ??

Comment: @CSharpBeginner . . . That doesn't matter.  If you want to select those other fields, then the query will need to reference the data pages, but that isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the where statement with another condition in the Join part

something like this

```
SELECT o.Id, o.Name, p.Id
FROM Order o
INNER JOIN Product p ON o.Id = p.OrderId
AND o.Name = 'TEST'
```

OR

```
SELECT o.Id, o.Name, p.Id
FROM (SELECT x.Id, x.Name Order x WHERE x.Name = 'Test') o
INNER JOIN Product p ON o.Id = p.OrderId
```